# Relationship b/w $QMA$ and $QCMA$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, quantum-computing

I was trying to read and understand about the complexity classes $QMA$ and $QCMA$:

$QMA$ is defined as the class with the set of problem such that, given a quantum certificate for any problem, its solution can be verified by a quantum computer in polynomial time.

$QCMA$ (as I undetstand) is defined as the class with the set of problem such that, given a classical certificate for any problem, its solution can be verified by a quantum computer in polynomial time.

Thus, the only difference between two classes seems to be the type of certificate.

Now given any $QMA-Complete$ problem, if we add an additional promise/constraint that the certificate is promised to be classical, does the resultant problem (with promise) automatically become $QCMA-Complete$?

It seems that this will be the case, but I need an external confirmation.

Comment: Interesting question. Let me ask for some clarification. A $QMA-Complete$ language is a pair $(L_{yes},L_{no})$ of disjoint languages. There's no notion of certificate in there as such. The problem statement is usually in informal prose, and also does not have a notion of 'certificate', e.g., "is this circuit the identity unitary?" What I'm asking is, what _precisely_ do you mean when you say you "add an additional promise that the certificate is... classical"? Do you modify the $(L_{yes},L_{no})$ pair? Go into the problem statement? Look at the Arthur's verifying quantum circuit?

Comment: Apologies for being a bit unclear (novice in QC). Lets consider any problem instance of a problem that is $QMA-Complete$. As I understand if a solution to it exists (i.e. $L_{yes}$) Merlin can always send a quantum certificate/solution to Arthur, and by definition Arthur can verify its correctness using a QC in polynomial time (lets ignore the error part). The promise is that: "For any $QMA-Complete$ problem instance, if its in $L_{yes}$ then the certificate will always be classical".

Comment: Does the above promise define the complexity class $QCMA-Complete$. Its seems be be the case but I am not sure?

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen if possible can you please opine on the above?

Comment: can anyone please clarify this ??

Comment: (1/2) Thanks for your reponse. What I'm asking is, can you define mathematically how you would transform a $QMA$-Complete language $(L_{yes},L_{no})$ to a pair of languages in your paradigm? How would the transformation work? Would it work for all pairs of languages? An obstacle that I see is that, for example, given the circuit that Arthur uses there may not always be a classical certificate with high acceptance probability; whereas it may be the case that Arthur there is a classical certificate if Arthur uses a different circuit.

Comment: (2/2) Here's an example; let me know if this is what you intended. Given a pair $(L_{yes},L_{no})\in QMA-complete$, let $K_{yes}\subseteq L_{yes}$ be the set of $x\in L_{yes}$ such that there exists a classical certificate which Arthur's Quantum Turing Machine accepts with $>2/3$ probability. If there exists a polynomial-time QTM which satisfies this description, then you conjecture that the promise language $(K_{yes},L_{no})$ is $QCMA$-Complete. That is, $K_{yes}$ is 'simply' the subset of $L_{yes}$ which can be $QCMA$-verified. Is this close to what you had in mind?

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen Thank you. I think its close to what I am saying. The 'promise' amounts to saying that, if for the certificate $x$, $x\in L_{yes}$ that it is also the case that $x\in K_{yes}$ thus, the promise language is $(K_{yes},L_{no})$. Thanks again. It answers my question.